# jQuery: Show post data before success

Tags: jquery

I'm not quite sure how to word the search, or what to look for with what I'm trying to. Basically, I want to set up a div to show data returned from a post/get with jQuery, similar to old batch files in windows command prompt.

```
function run_cache() {

  $.get("/run_cache.php", function(data) {  
    $('#update_div').html(data);  
  });   
  return false;

}
```

This is the basic code. Inside the run_cache.php it does something, then echo's some text. I want to display the text once it echo's. Right now that simple jQuery code will only post the data once the script it done running, and posts ALL the data that was echo'd.

Is there a way to post data as it's sent? Like, before the php file finishes.

Example:

run_cache.php does something and echo's 'Set 1 Complete'. The div gets updated with 'Set 1 Complete'. run_cache.php does something else, and echo's 'Set 2 Complete'. The div text then changes to 'Set 2 Complete'. Know what I mean?

Is this possible to do in jQuery? Or can data only be posted once the get/post form is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to send a message back to the client without the request being comlete, which means you'll have to make the request in steps to be able to update the page as each set or 'batch' is completed. The first step is making a request to find out how many 'steps' need to be completed. Then making seperate calls to request a step to be executed...recursively calling the same function to execute the next step.

```
var set_count = 0;
function get_set_count() {
   $.get("/get_set_count.php", function (data) {
      // populate the set_count variable from the returned data. could be xml or json. 
      // your choice.
      set_count = $(data).find('set_count').val();

      if (set_count > 0) {
        // kickoff the process, requesting set number 1.
        run_cache(1);
      } else {
        $('#update_div').html("No sets found.");
      }
  });
  return false;
}

function run_cache(set) {
  var url = "/run_cache.php?set=" + set;

  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $('#update_div').html(data);

    if (set < set_count) {
        // recursively request the next set.
        run_cache(set + 1);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Now that I think about it - you could probably get rid of the initial get_set_count() call by having run_cache.php return two pieces of data: the set that was just completed and next set number.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I was hoping there was some way to just show the data as it comes in. Sort of like fgets in php. Thanks for the help :P

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) something like this (how the data is formatted depends on what your server sends back):

```
function run_cache() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/run_cache.php',
    beforeSend: function() {
      // do something before sending data to server
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#update_div').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: .get() _is_ a jQuery AJAX function.

Comment: I don't want to do anything before sending the data. I want to post the data to the div as I get it back from the server. I want to grab the data as it's being sent, and not AFTER the success of the script it called.

Comment: @j08691 You're right, I didn't mean .get() wasn't an AJAX function.

Comment: @WMI I guess I didn't quite understand what you were going for. Seems like Brad has the answer you're looking for ;)